# Pulse pressure, vascular physiology

Tags: physiology, cardiology

I always though compliance of a vessel is a thing that prevents systolic pressure to goes up a lot and also prevents the diastolic pressure to goes down a lot, and that works because in arteriosclerosis we see that because of low compliance the systolic pressure goes up and diastolic pressure goes down therefore pulse pressure increases,

[image]

but I see a graph that shows systolic and diastolic pressure changes with age, we say with aging the compliance of vessels come down,but as you see in the below graph, both diastolic and systolic pressure goes up(I also find this sentence in the textbooks), why does diastolic pressure go up? Why it doesn’t go down like with arteriosclerosis? And also pulse pressure goes up with aging.

[image]

Both of the graphs are from Guyton, also I have this problem: What factors affect systolic and diastolic pressure? I search a lot but didn’t find anything.

Comment: The first figure does not show diastolic pressure going down with arteriosclerosis, does it?

Comment: I don’t see too, I just write what I’ve heard  in the class. unfortunately there is nothing about it in guyton.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for what makes a good question/answer on this site. This site values questions that show some evidence of previous research, of which there is plenty into blood pressure and arteriosclerosis etc. I'm not sure on your question here. The top graphs are point measurements of actual pressure over a single pulse-wave, but the second is average pressure with age. Why wouldn't the overall pressure increase with arteriosclerosis/age?

Comment: It would help if you were to focus down to a single question. At the moment it seems you want a complete rundown of all conditions that affect every aspect of blood pressure, that's too broad for this site's format. Please narrow to a single question, then ask any follow-up questions in their own threads.